# Extending list query look up from outside controller

Tags: octobercms

[The docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#extend-model-query) shows how to extend the look up query for a backend list from inside a controller using `listExtendQuery`
Can it be extended from outside the controller i.e from another plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Event in boot() function of your plugin

```
Event::listen('backend.list.extendQuery', function ($widget, $query) {
    // Check your model
    if ($widget->model instanceof \You\Plugin\Models\YourModel) {
        // extend $query
    }
}
```